# Should SEO microdata for Product include HTML markup in description

Tags: seo, schema.org

My output of product schema look like this.
Shell I remove the html code from `"meta itemprop="description" content="` or it must be plain text only?

```
<span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <meta itemprop="url" content="http://www.testest.com/bo-clark-collection.html" >
  <meta itemprop="name" content="Bo Clark Collection" >
  <meta itemprop="productID" content="1194" >
  <meta itemprop="description" 
     content="<html><body><div><p>Special eye-catcher: test.</p></body></html>" >   
  <span itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <meta itemprop="price" content="10,00 EUR" />
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="EUR" />
    <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock" />
  </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microdata should be embedded in HTML, but tags with microdata in them can contain HTML. Description is a `<meta>` tag in your code though, so it does not need the HTML because it will never be displayed.

It looks like you are putting key structured data in non-visible tags, that's OK for currency, price, dates, but [google states](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/policies) normally you should fit the microdata *around* your existing displayed data. The microdata can be in many different tags or block structures on the page, as long as they are nested under a single block structure (or a  - but  and  seem most useful).  Anything in HTML tags that don't have microdata will not cause problems -  it just gets ignored when searching structured data.

Consider altering your code so the microdata is spread out, eg

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
<meta itemprop="url" content="http://example.com/sales" />
<h3 itemprop="name">Bo Clark Collection</h3>
<img src.... >
   <strong>Product code:</strong><span itemprop="productID">1194</span> (in stock)<link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock">   
   <br> 
   <span itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">Price: <span itemprop="price">10,00</span><span itemprop="priceCurrency">EUR</span></span>
   <div itemprop="description">
    <p>Special eye-catcher: the silver Guess Wordmark test test.</p>
     <ul><li>Silver Guess Wordmark</li>
     <li>Leather in Croco-Style</li>
     <li>Inner lining Suede</li>
     <li>Tailor-made cutouts for ports and camera</li>
     <li>Color: <span itemprop="color">Black</span></li></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

One piece of microdata can be embedded within another, as I've done here with color (Black) which is also part of Description. It works well for list items.  Price done as above follows the google example of price.

Answer (score -1):

Yes.

You should only use plain text instead of html tags. Refer to the Product schema example at https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/products

Just write in following pattern:

```
<p itemprop="description">Special eye-catcher: the silver Guess Wordmark test test. Silver Guess Wordmark. Leather in Croco-Style. Inner lining Suede. Tailor-made cutouts for ports and camera. Color: Black</p>
```

It is recommended to use plain text in description as Google shows that description in plain text on their SERPs. In my view, Google only displays description in plain text rather than italic, bold or underlined fashion so using tags like ,  and  are irrelevant here.

Comment: that's not true, any type of HTML tag can be using including <em>, <i> and <strong>, normally styles are added to css, because that is good practice and keeps examples clearer, it does not say anywhere that I've seen that 'plain' tags are better (paragraph tags do include some formatting). Structured data has moved a long was from the old SERPs too.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying @Mousey.